# No UTF-8 / Polish characters in R console

Tags: r, encoding, locale, polish

The Polish characters are not appearing properly in the R console.

```
> a <- "Wrocław"
> a
[1] "Wroclaw"
```

This is with the following default locale settings:

```
> Sys.getlocale()
[1] "LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252;LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252;LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252;LC_NUMERIC=C;LC_TIME=English_United States.1252"
```

After running this:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "Polish")
```

I get this:

```
> a <- "Wrocław"
> a
[1] "Wroc³aw"
```

Apparently, something is wrong with my locale setup. How do I fix it?

My environment: R: 3.4.0 / Rstudio: 1.0.143 / OS: Windows 10

Comment: `Sys.setlocale(category = "LC_ALL", locale = "Polish")` _before_ `a <- "Wrocław"` works for me.

Answer (score 1):

This might have gotten fixed in RStudio 1.1 (released just a few days ago). See the related comment and associated thread at https://github.com/patperry/r-corpus/issues/5#issuecomment-335401743

Reportedly, this isn't an issue in RStudio 1.1. I haven't tested it myself.

On earlier versions, RStudio would not display native strings correctly when `LC_CTYPE` did not match the native locale (`Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "")`).

Answer (score 0):

Try this one as well:

https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding

In a nutshell: **File > Reopen with Encoding > [choose your encoding] > Set as default**